# Split string with single quote for each item in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have simple query...

```
Set @SQl1 = '415,417,418,419,420,416';
Set @SQl2 = REPLACE(@SQl1,","," ',' ");
Select @SQl1, @SQl2;
```

The result is -

```
@SQl1 = '415,417,418,419,420,416'
@SQl2 = '415 '','' 417 '','' 418 '','' 419 '','' 420 '','' 416'
```

But i Want result like this -

```
@SQL2 = '415','417','418','419','420','416'
```

Tried many functions like replace, Substring, json_unquote, quote.... but no success...

Anybody can help?

Comment: Unclear. Show needed value WITHOUT quote chars which quotes string literal. I.e. show not statement but the value only.

Comment: Maybe you need the value to be `'415','417','418','419','420','416'`? Which is `@SQL2 = '''415'',''417'',''418'',''419'',''420'',''416'''`?

Comment: Yes, i need to show values of @SQL2 = `'415','417','418','419','420','416'` like this

Comment: Basically i am receiving one string value `'415,417,418,419,420,416'` in `@SQl1` . Now i need to pass this `@SQl1` to another query by adding single quote to each element i.e. `'415','417','418','419','420','416'` to get desired result.
I am replacing `comma (,)` from `@SQl1` with `single quote comma single quote (',')` but its not working.

Comment: I see no reason to get duplicate quotes, and indeed I'm unable to replicate it in my machine. Can it be an artefact of whatever program you're using to display the query output? In any case, are you sure you want to follow the path of manipulating lists of numbers inside strings, as opposed to creating linked tables?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
Set @SQL1 = '415,417,418,419,420,416';
Set @SQL2 = CONCAT('''', REPLACE(@SQL1,',', ''','''), '''');
Select @SQL1, @SQL2;
```

Output

| @SQL1 | @SQL2 |
| --- | --- |
| 415,417,418,419,420,416 | '415','417','418','419','420','416' |

PS. Do not quote strings with doublequote chars `"` - they'd be used for JSON paths/values.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. It worked.

But i got stuck in another i.e. second query while passing @SQL2.

I think i need to explain Table and Query and Expected result.....

Comment: @user3733972 If you have another question then you'd create another topic. Please follow this while creating: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055), especially #5 and #3. You may refer to previous (this) topic if you think that this is reasonable.

Comment: Yes. Ok and thanks. I will create new topic.